# Название сторон

Tags: этимология

Вот интересно, почему в русском языке изменилось название сторон? Раньше было "одесную" - "справа", "ошую" - "слева". Откуда взялись тогда "право" или "лево"? Впрочем, "правый", видимо, от "быть правым", "правильно", а "левый"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не совсем точно говорите об истории названий.
Одесную и ошую - не просто слева и справа, а только слева или справа по отношению к говорящему или объекту действия (человеку). Десна и шуя - не названия сторон вообще, а только правой и левой рук соответственно. Наряду с этими названиями существовали с индоевропейских времен и названия "право" и "лево", правда значения их несколько менялись со временем, но как обозначения сторон они использовались с очень давних времен. "Правый" на праславянском уровне родственно "прямой", "правильный", "левые" - "кривой, изогнутый". Кстати, из этого следует, что представления о правом и левом как о истинном и ложном, правде и кривде имеет очень древние корни.